# generate all casses NUMBER LETTER NUMBER - php

Tags: php, generator

Hi I want to have a list of all possible cases from this arrays in this order

```
NUMBER LETTER NUMBER

$a = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$b = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
$c = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
```

It wil start with

```
0A0
```

and ends with

```
9Z9
```

I tried something like this:

```
foreach($a as $key1 => $first){
    foreach($b as $key2 => $second){
        foreach($c as $key3 => $third){
            print_r($first[$key1].$second[$key2].$key3[$key3]);
        }
    }
}
```

But its not working, any help?

Comment: Your variables aren't correct in `print_r` - `$first` is not an array inside your `foreach()` loop, it's a flat variable containing the individual array element, as are `$second` and `$third`. Generally, though, "its not working" isn't much help, tell us what it does incorrectly, what error messages you get, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array referencing is wrong. With a simple array when using a foreach the `$key` is almost irrelevant as the value of that occurance will be in `$first` or `$second` .......

```
foreach($a as  $first){
    foreach($b as $second){
        foreach($c as $third){
            echo $first . $second . $third . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are outputting this on a browser change `PHP_EOL` to `'<br>'`

Answer (score 0):

you solved it almost. you don't need to use key here. Here is the code

```
<?php

$a = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$b = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
$c = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

foreach($a as $first){
    foreach($b as $second){
        foreach($c as $third){
            echo ($first.$second.$third).PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```